# IOS Core Graphics redrawing

Tags: ios, button, rotation, core-graphics

So I'm drawing something in core graphics that I want to rotate when the user presses a button. In my storyboard I have a View and a button. I have a Cocoa Touch class that subclasses UIView and it the View's custom class is set to this subclass. In here I have a property used to store the amount of degrees that I want the drawing to rotate. In the '- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect' method I have

```
int lineRotate = self.rotationAmount;
UIBezierPath * line = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[line moveToPoint:CGPointMake(55.0, 55.0)];
[line addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(55.0, 25.0)];
[line applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-55, -55)];
[line applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(lineRotate * M_PI/180)];
[line applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(55, 55)];
[line setLineWidth: 5.0];
[[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
[line stroke];
```

I have a public method for setting this rotationAmount as well. From my ViewController class I import the UIView subclass that I created. I have a property for the class, I initialize it, etc. Calling this method to change the rotation amount followed by setNeedsDisplay from within the button's IBAction does nothing. What do I need to change or add so that the button works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is in the code you didn't show. The `UIViewController` shouldn't usually need to initialize a property for the `UIView`.  In the controller's methods, you can access the view as `self.view`, but you usually don't set it yourself.  Are you creating a second view and modifying the `rotationAmount` of that one, instead of  `self.view`?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)actionTapped:(id)sender {
_customView.rotationAmount = 50;
_customView.setNeedsDisplay;
}
```

Make sure you change the rotationAmount before you call setNeedsDisplay.
I created a project as you explained in your question. And I am able to rotate the line.

[image: The line is rotated 50 degress.]